# How to filter data of a big Firestore list?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

In the following code I am fetching users from a Firestore database and pass them to a View. The View has an input field to search users and filter the result while you are typing:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .onSnapshot((fetchedUsers) => {
       setUsers(fetchedUsers.docs.map((user) => user.data()));
    }).catch((error) => {
       // error handling
    });
  }, [setUsers]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search User..."
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        style={{ marginBottom: "30px" }}
      />
      {users
        .filter((e) => e.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
        .map((user) => (
          <div>{user.name}</div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am fetching users from Firestore and there are more than 1.000 users added every day. Thus, every access to the user list counts as many Firestore reads.

How can I reduce the amount of reads without loosing the possibility to search for users as I am typing? I am facing this issue, because when I add pagination or fetch the recent 50 users only, I have not the full list available to filter.

Answer (score 1):

On looking into firestore docs i found that it has querying support.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

If my understanding is correct you need to filter out the results, this can be delegated to firestore.

To reduce the number of calls you make to firestore you could implement `debounce`.

Comment: I think this is resolving my issue. In my real app I am already using Firestore. But I want to avoid fetching all users at once because there are many. But when I want to filter them reactively I some how need all - they are only required when I filter.

Comment: @T.Karter 
"Bcz i cant comment on above post, here;s what should work for you"

Basically you answered the question yourself.
You need to use a combination of filtering and limit(think pagination), but this needs to happen directly on firestore.

Bcz you want to reduce reads you cant fetch all the data and filter on client

1. Query on Firestore 2. Limit the results 3. Paginate

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: Pair above with debouncing and you can reduce the number of calls even further.

Comment: You mean pairing the timeout answer with debounce? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, it seems like you are wanting to limit calls to your firestore while the user is typing in the input element. To do this, I would use the `setTimeout` function in `useEffect` to delay calling firestore until `500 milliseconds` after the user stops typing. The changes to the `useEffect` function is below.

After implementing the timeout functions, you will need to filter through you data with the `where` function. This function accepts three parameters `([search for], '[operator]', [what to match])`, so, in your case, you will have `('name', '==', search)`. Look below for the code, [and check out the documentation for firestore queries](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries).

```
useEffect(() => {

 // Adding the search variable to the array of the second useEffect argument
 // will cause this useEffect to run on every change to the search variable, which
 // is what we want since we do not know when the user will stop typing.

 // Also to filter user's, use the 'where' function, which has three parameters.

 const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('name', 'in', search)
    .onSnapshot((fetchedUsers) => {
       setUsers(fetchedUsers.docs.map((user) => user.data()));
    .catch(err => {
      // catch error
    });
 }, 500);

 // Clean up timeout
 return () => clearTimeout(timeout)

}, [search, setUsers]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to rephrase my question. I have e.g. 2.000 users and currently I fetch all, what means 2.000 reads. I could add pagination to only fetch 10 for example. This is what I want basically, but when I do that, I can't use the filter, because I only have 10 users to filter and I want to filter all.

Comment: @T.Karter So basically, your filter loops through all 2,000 users to find the ones that match a certain criteria, and you don't want it to do that correct?

Comment: That's the point - somehow I would say I need all users to be able to filter them. But I'm not always filtering. It would be fine, to display the last 10 users with pagination. So basically the first fetch has a `.limit(10)`. But when I now want to filter, I need all I think. Or there is a trick on filtering in Firestore and only read the filtered results.

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know the firestore API, but if you are fetching all 2,000 users per request and filtering through them in your React app, you need to find the filter method for the firestore API. The reason for this is, as the amount of users increase in your application, you could be forcing the client to sort through thousands of users on each search, which is extraordinarily bad for performance.

Comment: @T.Karter I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But when I understand this correctly, I am reading more from the database and not less?